# Calculation causing span to crash

Tags: c#, jquery

Cacluation is braking function I am trying to do a calculation but it is braking my other functions the calculation is simple to take  away one span from another span

Jquery

```
 function caclulateBalance() {
          incomescic = +$('#sumTotalIncome').text();
          expensecic = +$('#expendureTotalSum').text();
          reducible = +$('#reducibleSumTotal').text();
          incomes = +$('#totalsIncomeiande').text();
          expenses = +$('#totalexpensessum').text();                     


          $('#Total').text(incomescic - expensecic + reducible ).toFixed(2);              
}
```

Html

```
Income: <strong><span id="totalbalancesum">143</span></strong>

expenses:<strong><span id="totalbalancesum">143</span></strong>
<span id="expenses" >60</span>

Reducible: <strong><span id="reducibleSumTotal">143</span></strong>
<span id="expenses" >60</span>

<span id="Total" >answer should be 23 and displayed here</span>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] to demonstrate your problem. Or at very least provide your HTML so we can see what sort of elements you're using.

Comment: you can't do toFixed after you appended it to the page

Comment: @madalinivascu thanks can you explain in a answer as how to fix this ?

Comment: @dave you just need to apply the function to the value directly

Comment: so do it after the .Val().toFixed(2) is that what you are saying ? what i need to make sure though is take away those two values from that one but they must be added together first.

Comment: yes but first you need to parse the value to a float, see my answer bellow

Comment: @madalinivascui see you answer but i dont see you parsing it to a float anywhere how do i do this

Comment: @dave - are you kidding? Can you not see all the `parseFloat` in that answer? Also, youve added some HTML, but the field names do not match your javascript function at all! You're not making helping you particularly easy.

Comment: @Jamiec sorry it was not eidted by time i saw it i see it now thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the elements are inputs do the following

```
function caclulateBalance() {

         var incomescic = parseFloat($('#sumTotalIncome').text()),
          expensecic = parseFloat($('#expendureTotalSum').text()),
          reducible = parseFloat($('#reducibleSumTotal').text()),
          incomes = parseFloat($('#totalsIncomeiande').text()),
          expenses = parseFloat($('#totalexpensessum').text()),
          total = (incomescic - expensecic + reducible).toFixed(2);
          $('#totalbalancesum').text(total);



      }
```

Comment: thank you for the instance the caluation needs be more like this though $('#lblTotalcicSum').text(incomescic - (expensecic + reducible)).toFixed(2); as its income - expnses + reducible is that the right way of doing the calculation

Comment: @dave - you have a bracket in the wrong place there.

Comment: @Jamiec can you see my comment on undneth there thats what the caulation should be can you provide an answer please

Comment: @dave - can you see my comment under your question, do that and I'll happily provide you an answer.

Comment: @Jamiec i have inlcuded the sample I just want to use this to explain my probelm in what i am having

Comment: Sorry when i do this as a test it still fales ?

           alert('test' + (incomescic).toFixed(2));

              total = (incomescic).toFixed(2)
              $('#lblTotalcicSum').text(total);

Comment: it is still priting NAN for me sorry

Comment: how do you trigger this function??

Comment: I trigger it on       $(document).ready(function () {
calculateBalance();
}

The control values are loaded in .net code behind on page load so maybe that is not the correct place to execute the jquery is their a page finished loading event in jquery i should be running this on ?

Comment: what type of elements are `$('#sumTotalIncome')`,`$('#expendureTotalSum')` etc, inputs,spans,paragrafs,what?

Comment: @madalinivascu they are spans as well so they are,

Comment: @madalinivascu its still not givng me the desired result mate the values are 266 - 352 + 128 should equal -214 but with the the current application its giving me 42 as the balance result